how d i fix this number of digits counter in C lang code?
#include <stdio.h>

int digits(int n);

int main()
{
    int c, d;
    while ((c = scanf("%d", &d)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d \n", digits(d));
    }
    return 0;
}

int digits(int n)
{
    int p;
    if (n < 10)
    {
        p++;
        return p;
    }
    else 
    {
        p++;
        n /= 10;
        digits(n);
    }
}

i expected it to recursively increase p but it always returns 1 or some other number that is not intended what should I do to make it run correctly?

You need to initialize p to a value. Also your code formatting is all over the place, which isn't exactly helping you spotting trivial bugs like that yourself.

Aside: while ((c = scanf("%d", &d)) != EOF) should be while ((c = scanf("%d", &d)) == 1). Otherwise the code will stall when you make a non-integer entry. Although there is no need for c here anyway, so while (scanf("%d", &d) == 1)

@yahia98 In any case if even the local variable p will be initialized nevertheless the code of the function is incorrect because in each recursive call of the function you are changing the local variable p that will not be alive after exiting a call.

You need to return a value from digits and use that returned value in the recursive call.  Something like int digits(int n) { return n < 10 ? 1 : 1 + digits(n/10); }

@yahia98 Another problem with the function is that its parameter has the signed integer type int. It means that the user may pass a negative value to the function. In this case for each negative multidigit value the function will return 1 due to the if statement if (n < 10)

Question was changed so as to remove the problems. Don't do that. If you want to answer your own question, that's fine, but post it as an answer. Rolled back.
